# internet explorer issue with sencha extjs 4

Tags: extjs

I have a web site it works in chrome and firefox, but in ie9 I got this "unable to get value of the property 'ref' object is null or undefined", the error is in ext-all-debug.js, somebody  know about this?

thanks

Comment: It's probably impossible to answer such a vague question; add as much relevant code as possible (but as little as necessary), use the debugger to break on error and see the stacktrace to determine which line of YOUR code is causing it.

Comment: I know that is a vague question, the code is huge, I only want to have some idea for this problem, maybe some extra comma or something else.